# Use nested records in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use nested java records in Spring MVC like so:

Definition:

```java
public record RankDto(String rank, long rankNumber);
public record WorkersDto(String firstName, RankDto rankDto){};
```

Controller via http POST:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String edit(@ModelAttribute("worker") WorkersDto workersDto){
   return userService.edit(workersDto);
}
```

EDIT:
When i try this example i got this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException
Could not instantiate property type RankDto to auto-grow nested property path
```

EDIT #2:
Maybe this is an open issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28996

Comment: Yes it is possible. Anything what can be serialized as JSON will work as a request body (and response).

Comment: Thank you. It´s not working. See my edit.

Comment: OK. I missed your point. You want to use the new Java record. I meant nested object like Java bean or POJO. With a non-arg constructor and setters. Java record can't have none of it.